# Download tcpdf manually without using composer in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, tcpdf

I'm trying to download TCPDF library to my project using Composer (Laravel 4), but I can't.

Sometimes this error occurs

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaPDz.jpg)[image: http://mahdedu.org/1.jpg]

and sometime this error

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/quXMB.jpg)[image: http://mahdedu.org/2.jpg]

I want to download it and add it in laravel manually without using composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "without using `composer`", I'm going to assume you mean "without using `composer` for the download". With the following solution you'll still need to invoke a `composer` command, but its just to get the library auto-loading.

First step is to find a folder that makes sense for storing your local copy of TCPDF. I would recommend *against* using the vendor folder, because that folder is largely (solely?) managed by `composer`. For the sake of demonstration, let's create a new folder called `app/vendor`. Not the best choice, I know, but this is just a demonstration of one possible solution. Download TCPDF, unzip it and move the resulting `tcpdf` folder into `app/vendor` (so you should end up with `app/vendor/tcpdf`).

Second step is to add this folder to the autoload section of `composer.json`, as follows:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/vendor/tcpdf" // <== HERE IT IS
    ]
```

Finally, run `composer dump-autoload`.

You should now be able to use the TCPDF library within your code without any external download dependencies. I tested this solution on a clean copy of Laravel 4.1 and it worked fine.

*If anybody has a more appropriate suggestion as to the location of the `tcpdf` folder, please add a comment.*