# Trying to get tcpdf installed on my laravel website?

Tags: html, laravel, tcpdf

I will refer to the account as user in this post.

So I put the tcpdf directory in /home/user/laravel/

I then tried to do this in a page:

```
{{ HTML::link('/tcpdf/examples/example_001.php') }}
```

and I get the 404 requested page that I setup

[image]

any ideas why this is happening or why its not working?
Do I need to do a route maybe?

Any information on this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are really trying to work with `TCPDF` within your Laravel app, you will most likely want to include it as you would other packages using `composer`. Please see this answer on how to add `TCPDF` to `composer.json` in order to have `composer` automatically download it into your vendor area: [Download tcpdf manually without using composer in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144229/download-tcpdf-manually-without-using-composer-in-laravel-4/22162389#22162389) (Ignore the post title - it does talk about including `TCPDF` **with** `composer`.)

What you are achieving with the code sample above is to simply render a link to a certain URI off your URL base. Whether or not that will work will depend on how your local web server is configured and potentially how Laravel and Laravel routing is configured.

Having said all that, I think you are headed down the wrong path with that solution. Ultimately, I believe that what you will want to do is drag `TCPDF` in using `composer`, then create a PDF file with code like:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf-> ... other stuff according to the TCPDF API...
$pdf->Output( 'test.pdf', 'I' );
```

The `TCPDF` API can be found here: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html

You could put some code like that into a controller method to play around and get things working, but later you would probably want to move it elsewhere.

Comment: I actually did figure this out and I used exactly what you mentioned above is installed a vendor using composer which made this REALLY easy.

What JamesG said to do above is exactly right!